# java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero error

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm getting a divide by zero error which makes no sense because both of my variables have data on them.

```
String str = "54";
int i = 0, b = 0;

while(i < str.length()){
    b = b + Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(str.charAt(i)));
    i++;
}

int ratings = (b / str.length());
```

This is the line the error is referring to, b has a value of 9 (It is an integer) and str has a length of 2 (which also is an integer).

When I try to access the division it gives me this error, but if I access both variables I get their values without any problem.

I have also tried to create a separate variable called strLength and retrieved the length on there but the error persists.

Comment: Are you sure that str contains the value it should? Add this line - `System.out.println(""+str.length());` before the divison just to make sure.

Comment: Computers don't lie! Can you post the code before this line?

Comment: There are really two possibilities:  either `str.length()` really is zero for some reason, or the error is coming from some other code.  If you only show us one line of code, it's really hard for us to say what exactly is going on.

Comment: strange... seems like it suddenly turns the str.length to 0 right before the division, will try and find a solution

Comment: int strLength = str.length();

        int i = 0, b = 0;

        while(i < str.length()){
            b = b + Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(str.charAt(i)));
            i++;
        }

Comment: edited the post

Comment: Can you please explain downvotes? If you do think the question is stupid at least help me...

Comment: I would guess the downvotes are mostly because your problem isn't reproducible without str's value. We are left guessing what the value might be..

Comment: I think we need to know exactly how you know the error is coming from this line, and exactly how you know that str contains a value.  Maybe one of your assumptions is wrong.  If you manually set str to be "ab" or something in this function, does it then work?

Comment: You need to show us more code than this, if we are to understand why `str` does not contain the value that you think it does.  Is it possible that you have two variables of the same name? For example, a local variable and a field, both called `str` but with different values?

Comment: my problem is that I have a String of numbers, right now it is 54, but it will change in the future. I have to extract all digits from the string and add them up, convert it to an integer and then divide by the length of that string (I have to do an average)

Comment: Then your codeblock should start with `String str = "54";`

Comment: Str is "54", a sting, I have to do 5+4 and divide by the length of the string (2)

Comment: No, there is only 1 variable called str in the whole project, this 54 I get from JSON object from mysql

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger, and examining all the relevant variables at each step?

Comment: If I copy&paste your current code => no error. it works

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6HsDYr3F error log, will debug variables now

Comment: Sorry, but there **has to be** a difference between your actual code and/or str's value compared to what you posted here. Post a screenshot of your code ?

Comment: alex, doesn´t work for me

Comment: So now you have JSON and MySQL. Anything else?

Comment: TDG, forget the JSON and MYSQL part, it isnt relevant. alex 1 sec

Comment: http://picpaste.com/pics/Untitled-m6zZL10m.1485286041.png

Comment: You didn't do anything like include your own `String` class in the project did you?  That's really a `java.lang.String`?

Comment: really strange thing happens while debugging, everything is working properly until it gets to the int ratings = (b / str.length());. When it gets here, str is "54", but it suddenly changes to "" and the exception ocurrs. The debugger then shows code "if (builder.length() == 0 && s != null) {", but after this, if I do step out and step in again, it runs correctly and ratings gets value of 4 (9/2, but it isnt double)...

Comment: Is this being executed locally ? If you are debuggin remotely, it is possible you are stepping into "old code" while still viewing "updated code".

Comment: Yes David, I did not modify the String class at all, nor the log

Comment: I´m debugging with my phone

Comment: that must be it then! The phone still has the "old code"

Comment: never mind, even when str goes with value "54" the app still crashes with the same log

Comment: Ill run on bluestacks and see

Comment: Can you clean out your build directory?  Just to make sure you really are running the latest version of the code?

Comment: done, still crashing... It looks like the variable str loses its value right after the wile loop

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134216/discussion-on-question-by-juan-pablo-gallego-java-lang-arithmeticexception-divi).

Answer (score 0):

I can not simulate your problem, but I did an example and it works correctly. However, when str is empty, the java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero error occurs. Please post more information if the error persists.

Exemple:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int b = 9;
    String str = "AB";

    int ratings = (b / str.length());

    System.out.println(ratings);
}
```

Comment: my problem is that I have a String of numbers, right now it is 54, but it will change in the future. I have to extract all digits from the string and add them up, convert it to an integer and then divide by the length of that string (I have to do an average)

Comment: You may post example of String numbers?

Comment: By his explanation I understood thus:     

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "12345"; //123456...............54
        String[] x = a.split("");
        int add = 0;
        for (String x1 : x) {
            add += Integer.parseInt(x1);
        }

        System.out.println("Avarage: " + (add / a.length()));

    }